# PHP Media storage , media input in page

Tags: php, oracle

How could I store my media files (pictures, videos etc)? I am building a simple web app like a social website ,using php. I don't really know how could I save my pictures in a datbase for the moment when I log in with a certain user, i can see all his data (pictures, etc). And how could I link more pictures, for example if I have a "add image" button in the middle of page, i want to upload as more photos as i want, and for every photo using a storage method.

Comment: Usually in database, we store only name/image url. Images are being store in another server or the local server folder. 

if its a one to many relationship, u will need a another table to store image url with user_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to store the image names in a database.

For example -

You could create a table in the database called "posts" or "images" and store the image file name in the table and associate it to the user who uploaded it.

Example table structure could be: id, user_id, image_name

You will then write a query to get the images by the users ID stored in that table.

It's fairly simple and I've done it many times.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yup, it sounds simple, and If I put the base64 image's url in my database , wouldn't it be more efficient ?

Comment: Not necessarily... base64 encoding an image makes the file name incredibly long. Almost so long that some browsers may not even load the file because of it's length. You may want to generate a short random string and include the current timestamp and the users ID along with it (to ensure the file name will always be unique) for renaming files upon uploading them. If indeed that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Alright ,I got it, thanks a lot :) ,I'll try to do it with  the timestamp to have short unique resources.

Comment: Not a problem. If I answered your question, please do me favor and tick that green check mark for me :)

Comment: Couldn't have said it better @JasonBassett